# Disabling Rider Auto Inline of Unity SerializeField

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rider

In the recent i find really disturbing that Rider put automatically inline my fields on a class when i use properties on them.

[image: Here is the Example in a GIF]

How can i disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open settings and go to Editor > Code Style > C# > Line Breaks and Wrapping

and then find Arrangement of Attributes

[image]